# Client filter does not work in alethes:meteor-pages

Tags: meteor, filter, pagination

I set auth function:

```
UsersPagination = new Meteor.Pagination(Meteor.users, {
    templateName: "usersPaginate",
    itemTemplate: "userListItem",
    router: "iron-router",
    homeRoute: "/userlist/",
    route: "/userlist/",
    routerTemplate: "userListPage",
    routerLayout: "indexLayout",
    perPage: 50,
    sort: {createdAt: -1},
    auth: function(skip, sub){
        //use alanning:roles
        if(Roles.userIsInRole(sub.userId, ['admin'])) { // see all users
            return Meteor.users.find({roles: 'user', user_status: {$in: [1,2,3,4,5]}}, {fields: {services: 0}});
        } else if(Roles.userIsInRole(sub.userId, ['manager'])) { // see own users
            return Meteor.users.find({manager_id: sub.userId, roles: 'user', user_status: {$in: [1,2,3,4,5]}}, {fields: {services: 0}});
        } else {
            console.log('whaa?');
            return false ;
        }
    },
    divWrapper: false,
    fastRender: true,
    availableSettings: {
        filters: true,
        settings: true
    }
});
```

and if i set filter "user_status" in template:

```
Template.usersPaginate.events({
   'change #user_status': function(event, template){ //select input
       var status_id = parseInt(event.currentTarget.value) ;
       var filter = {} ;
       if(status_id !== 0) {
           filter.user_status = status_id ;
       }
       //....
       UsersPagination.set({
           filters: filter
       });
   }
});
```

it's not working, template refresh, but filter not working. Displays all users.
Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.
Sorry my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

The combination auth and filter seems bugged or not clearly documented. Make your own pagination. You will spend less time in the end.

Comment: how to have the pagination for two view on same event but different functinality  ?